# How can i reset Thaumcraft 4 in world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I have Mystcraft and was thinking about creating a new Age with it where I can start from scratch with the option to retreat back to my original age if I want (particular if I want to rebuild some of my buildings). However, one of the things that would carry over between Ages would be the research I have done in Thaumcraft.

Is there a way I can reset my research without need to create a brand new world?

Answer (score 3):

In game this can be done with a simple command: `/thaumcraft research <playername> reset`, where `<playername>` is your Minecraft username.

Comment: Note you won't get it back by returning to your original Age.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, yes you can reset your personal thaumcraft research without having to wipe the world.

What you want to do is find the world folder for the current world you are playing on. If you are on a server you can find this folder at the root of install location of the server. If you are in single player you want to go into the saves folder and find your current world.

Once in there you need to find the `playerdata` folder. Inside of this folder you will find a file that looks like this.

`solignis.thaum`

And this

`solignis.thaumback`

Wipe both of them out and you are all set.

Do this while the game is off and start the game back up. When you log back in you will still have the Thaunomicon but it will back to the start.